# Jupyter notebook started from rc.local does not pick up exported environment variables?

Tags: python, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, jupyter-notebook

I am on an AWS GPU instance and am using rc.local to start Jupyter Notebook:

`/etc/rc.local` contains:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin:$PATH                                                                                          
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64                                                                                                                                                            
sudo su ubuntu -c 'bash /home/ubuntu/OnStartJupyter.sh'                                                                            
exit 0
```

So when my aws instance turns on the commands above should execute.

`/home/ubuntu/OnStartJupyter.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                        
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin:$PATH                                                                                          
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64                                                                                   
nohup sudo ipython notebook --profile=nbserver &
```

However, when I open up a jupyter notebook and look at my environment variables:

```
import os
os.environ
```

I do not see the exports I have done. I only see:

```
{'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'USERNAME': 'root', 'TERM': 'xterm-color', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'JPY_PARENT_PID': '1383', 'SUDO_COMMAND': '/usr/local/bin/ipython notebook --profile=nbserver', 'PAGER': 'cat', 'SUDO_UID': '1000', 'SUDO_GID': '1000', 'CLICOLOR': '1', 'LOGNAME': 'root', 'USER': 'root', 'MAIL': '/var/mail/root', 'PATH': '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin', 'SUDO_USER': 'ubuntu', 'HOME': '/home/ubuntu', 'GIT_PAGER': 'cat'}
```

What can be done to export variables so that Jupyter Notebook started from within rc.local has access to those exported variables?

(This is important because I have a python library, tensorflow, which requires that I have certain environment variables specifying the location of CUDA)

Comment: More generally, starting an interactive program from `rc.local` seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Maybe see also http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83194/19240

Comment: @tripleee do you know what is a better method to start an interactive program onstartup so that it jacks into .bashrc content?

Comment: Start it from your personal desktop login scripts instead of on startup if that's what you actually need it for. If not, perhaps explain your use case in more detail.

Comment: `sudo env "PATH=$PATH" start_stuff` worked! Thanks for that link :)